# How can I implement a twocolumn template

Tags: templates, marginpar, double-sided

How can I implement such template (two columns):

[image: screenshot]

In my case additional panel can contain images.

Comment: Will the additional panel contain text, or is it just a margin?

Comment: In can contain text ... but mostly images which are anchored to some text in 'Main text' block. 'Additional panel' block had to be present on all pages

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please only ask one question per question post. I think your follow-up questions have been asked here before, but you'll have to check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you want a `twosided` document. In the MWE I have used

- the `geometry` package to set up the page dimensions
- the `caption` package to provide the `captionof` command, used in the margin figures
- the `changepage` package to give the extra width environment that you wanted.

I have also loaded the `lipsum` package for sample text, and the `graphicx` package to include images.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[left=7cm,right=1cm,showframe=true,                  % page settings (showframe is useful!)
    top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}               
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}

\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}

\marginpar{
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{myfig}
\captionof{figure}{My Figure}}
\lipsum

\lipsum

\marginpar{
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{myfig}
\captionof{figure}{My Figure}}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{adjustwidth}{-7cm}{}
\lipsum[2]
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

Note that you'll want to remove `showframe=true` from the `geometry` load, and `[demo]` from the `graphicx` load- these were just for demonstration.

Comment: Very-very helpful! Thanks a lot. I had one question more concerned this topic. ... Currently I don't know, should I ask it in different question with link to this one .... I would like to anchor images on the additional panel with piece of text in the main panel. I mean ... when the text in the main panel will be shifted (up\down) --> the image will be shifted too ...

Comment: One more notice .... \begin{adjustwidth}{-7cm}{} on the odd pages (2,4,..) works incorrect .. text are shifted far away from the page (to the left side)

Comment: @davs There is a starred version of `adjustwidth` which helps to deal with the odd/even page problems that you describe. Have a look at the documentation for details. By default, `\marginpar` is anchored to its surrounding text- if it's not exactly what you want, then a new question might be in order

Comment: Did [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) complain about an over-specification in the vertical direction? If so, the `height` specification is superfluous.

Comment: @Werner Thanks, of course you're correct; I removed it