# Why the checklist box was put on the left

Tags: boxes

I just create a simple check list following the way described here: [How do I generate a check-list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58752/how-do-i-generate-a-check-list), My code is below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[]{ctex}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[twocolumn]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rowno}
\setcounter{rowno}{0}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % draw frame of the image
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm,headheight=1cm,headsep=1cm,footskip=1cm}


\usepackage{wasysym}     

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.2in}
\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand\marginpar[1]{\-\oldmarginpar[\raggedleft #1]%
{\raggedright #1}}    

\newenvironment{checklist}{%
  \begin{list}{}{}% whatever you want the list to be
  \let\olditem\item
  \renewcommand\item{\olditem -- \marginpar{$\Box$} }
  \newcommand\checkeditem{\olditem -- \marginpar{$\CheckedBox$} }
}{%
  \end{list}
}   

\begin{document}
\begin{checklist}
  \checkeditem   Open the \TeX book
  \checkeditem   Find the good page
  \item   Try to understand
\end{checklist}
\end{document}
```

The question is, here I use twocolumn option, but you see the checkitem box was put on the left, why? Can you help me, thanks.

See the screen shot image below:

[image: check box on left page]

EDIT:
This is the new code. I use the

```
\documentclass[a4paper,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[twocolumn]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % draw frame of the image
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm,headheight=1cm,headsep=1cm,footskip=1cm}

\usepackage{wasysym}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5in}

\newcommand\numitem[1]{\item #1 \hfill $\Box$}%
\newcommand\nonnumitem[1]{\item[--] #1 \hfill $\Box$}%


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \numitem{Open the \TeX book Open the \TeX book Open the abc}
  \numitem{Find the good page}
  \nonnumitem{Try to understand}
\end{enumerate}

\newpage

\begin{enumerate}
  \numitem{Open the \TeX book Open the \TeX book Open the abcdefg}
  \numitem{Find the good page}
  \nonnumitem{Try to understand}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I found a bug that sometimes, the box was not put in the right side of the column, see the screen shot below:
[image: box shown on the left]

So, any idea to fix this? Thanks.

**EDIT2**
I found some code snippet which can solve this issue(force the box go to the right side), just change the code to:

```
\newcommand\numitem[1]{\item #1 \unskip\linebreak[0]\enspace\hbox{}\nobreak\hfill$\Box$}%
\newcommand\nonnumitem[1]{\item[--] #1 \unskip\linebreak[0]\enspace\hbox{}\nobreak\hfill$\Box$}%
```

Then, I can fix this bug, but can any till me what does the code means? Thanks.

Comment: This is because, in `twocolumn` mode, the margin used to print the `\marginpar` is the left one when you are in the left column and the right one when you are in the right column.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, are there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: OK, I understand this issue now, there is a nice image showing that the margin position in the twocolumn mode, see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35833/how-can-i-implement-a-twocolumn-template, but I still need a way to handle my original question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution you're referring to doesn't work in two column mode, because the margin used to print the `\marginpar` is the left one when you are in the left column and the right one when you are in the right column.

This is a simple solution that doesn't use the margins to print the checkboxes, but it's far from perfect.

I've defined two new commands

```
\newcommand\noncheckeditem[1]{\item[--] #1 \hfill $\Box$}%
\newcommand\checkeditem[1]{\item[--] #1 \hfill $\CheckedBox$}%
```

to be used respectively when you want a non-checked and a checked item.

You can use them inside a normal `description` environment as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[twocolumn]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % draw frame of the image
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm,headheight=1cm,headsep=1cm,footskip=1cm}

\usepackage{wasysym}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5in}

\newcommand\noncheckeditem[1]{\item[--] #1 \hfill $\Box$}%
\newcommand\checkeditem[1]{\item[--] #1 \hfill $\CheckedBox$}%

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \checkeditem{Open the \TeX book}
  \checkeditem{Find the good page}
  \noncheckeditem{Try to understand}
\end{description}

\newpage

\begin{description}
  \checkeditem{Open the \TeX book}
  \checkeditem{Find the good page}
  \noncheckeditem{Try to understand}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that I've printed one on the left and one on the right column just to see how they look. For this purpose, I've also added the lines

```
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.5in}
```

Also note that the left and the right margin of your `geometry` are too small and you get warnings. You should put something like `3.5cm` both for `lmargin` and `rmargin`.

Comment: Dear karkoeller, many thanks, your solution is really good. I will adjust the margin width, thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi Karlkoeller, sorry for bother again, I still see a bug in your code, sometimes, the box are still put in the left, I have show the code and screen shot in my updated original question, can you give a hand? Thanks.

Comment: The EDIT2 section in my original post fix this bug, but I don't why.

Comment: @ollydbg23 as I said, my answer was far from perfect. I'm happy that you've found a workaround for critical cases, but I'm not able to explain exactly what that code does. I can only tell you that it creates an empty horizontal box (`\hbox{}`) that keeps the `\Box` in the same line when there is enough space, otherwise puts it in the next line at end of it.